# Mips : asciiz vs ascii , Printing many variables

Tags: mips

I know that (asciiz) string is terminated by '\0' where (ascii) is not.
But I am still very confused. In this code, why does it print:

> 'One Two Three Three Four Five Five'

Instead of simply printing them in the same sequence as the printing commands?

```
.data
str1: .asciiz"One"    
str2: .ascii " Two"
str3: .asciiz" Three"  
str4: .ascii " Four" 
str5: .ascii" Five" 
.text

main:
la $a0,str1
li $v0,4
syscall

#---------------------------
la $a0,str2
li $v0,4
syscall
#---------------------------
la $a0,str3
li $v0,4
syscall
#---------------------------
la $a0,str4
li $v0,4
syscall
#---------------------------
la $a0,str5
li $v0,4
syscall
#---------------------------
#End
li $v0, 10
syscall
.end main
```

Answer (score 4):

A NUL-terminator (`'\0'`) is necessary for the `print_string` syscall to know where the string ends. The system call will keep on printing characters until it reaches a NUL-terminator.

Printing `str1` prints `One`.

Printing `str2` prints `Two Three`, since `str2` isn't NUL-terminated.

Printing `str3` prints `Three`.

Printing `str4` prints `Four Five`, since `str4` isn't NUL-terminated.

Printing `str5` prints `Five`.

Put all those together and you get `One Two Three Three Four Five Five`.